# How to describe a person who has many faces inside him

Tags: metaphors, figures-of-speech, personification

I need a phrase to describe a person who has many faces such as good, bad, pure soul, kind but also evil. A person who can't be judged or categorised.

Comment: faces inside him? Wow, how would you even represent that graphically? multi-faced gorgon.

Comment: I'm struggling to see how a person can be both kind and evil.  Do you mean a person who can act so that many people believe s/he is good, when their other actions show they really are not?

Comment: When a question attracts a long list of answers, that usually means it is subjective – more of a poll or request for ideas. Unfortunately neither are a good fit for the Stack Exchange model. A Stack Exchange question is objective and specific enough that it has one clearly “right” answer. See: “[Real questions have answers, not items or ideas or opinions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/)”, “[Single word requests, crosswords, and the fight against mediocrity](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2160)”.

Comment: If possible, add more details of research you’ve done, especially solutions you’ve already rejected, and why. Include the desired connotation, register (formality), part of speech, and context in which it is to be used, and provide the exact enclosing sentence or passage. If this is not possible because you really do have a subjective question, a welcoming place to ask for advice is our [English Language & Usage Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95).

Answer (score 1):

Sound like a *complex, multifaceted individual*.

http://www.yourdictionary.com/multifaceted

> **multifaceted**
>
> adjective
>       1   The definition of multifaceted is someone or something with many features or perspectives to consider.     >*A person who has many different talents in all kinds of fields and subject areas is an example of someone who would be described as multifaceted.*

Answer (score 0):

a person of many [**personalities**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/personalities)

> the sum total of all the behavioural and mental characteristics by
>   means of which an individual is recognized as being unique

As in:

> Her “Judge” was goofy, charming and sinisterly **unreadable** —
>   perhaps her strongest-ever flexing of her ability to embody multiple
>   **personalities** concurrently. New York TimesSep 13, 2018

Answer (score 0):

Update: [**will-o'-the-wisp**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/will-o'-the-wisp).

> A person or thing that is difficult or impossible to reach or catch

So in this context the example

> He was a will-o'-the-wisp, more of a concept than a man

works.

---

Previously:

The question isn't clearly defined. You know about the person, but also say "A person who can't be judged or categorised."

Two suggestions:

[**Impenetrable**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/impenetrable) (meaning 2)

> Her expression was impenetrable

[**Inscrutable**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/inscrutable)

> Guy looked blankly inscrutable

Or perhaps a [**fake**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/fake)

> Claiming to be something that one is not.

because someone can't be all of those things.

Answer (score 0):

I used the term "**mood swings**" for such a person once.

> The context was that their last name was "Morin", so I referred to
>   them as "**Mood swings Morin**".

I think it should work with almost anyone though. Good luck.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mood_swing